# Rendering the skin using VTK

Tags: 3d, rendering, vtk, dicom

I am developing an application in windows forms that reads a sequence of 2d dicom images and transform them into a 3d object. I can do it pretty well for bones using the VTK framework, but when trying to do the same for the skin, I am getting a blank screen. Does anyone have the same issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the rendering image's Window [Width](http://www.medilexicon.com/medicaldictionary.php?t=99895) and [Level](http://www.medilexicon.com/medicaldictionary.php?t=49213) in accordance with the calibrated [Hounsfield Units?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hounsfield_scale)

Are you using `vtkPievewiseFunction` in the vtk rendering pipeline? Add points to it where `(x,y)`

- x = hounsfield unit for the organ, y = 1.0f
- x = -10,000, y = 0.0f
- x = +10,000, y = 0.0f

You'll have to refine the algorithm, but that should get you started.